# VirtualBox input goes crazy after guest additions with migrated Windows 7 RC

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am re-paving windows 7 as the RC has begun to complain. I want to keep the previous RC install in a VM for reference (in case I forget anything).

- I have snapshotted the main drive with Sysinternals Disk2VHD.
- I installed virtual box and set up a new Win 7 VM based on the VHD above.
- It runs OK the first boot, then I try to install guest additions.
- Note: A second boot without guest additions booted to a black screen with the build number in white in the corner. I rolled back the snapshot when this happened.

After guest additions are successfully installed the input goes crazy. With mouse integration on I get what appears to be constant left and right clicks at the mouse location. When I turn off mouse integration the menus and such on the right hand side start popping up and disappearing.

Does Windows 7 work correctly in a VirtualBox VM? With Guest Additions?

What might be wrong here?

Edit: Found it was the mouse drivers. Adding some keywords for future searchers: Eratic Mouse Behavior Click Clicking randomly right left buttons right side of screen set point Logitec

Comment: No idea why this is happening but can confirm Windows 7 RTM works very happily in VirtualBox without issues. I have 2 test VM's setup with it and they are very happy little machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out this was the 'SetPoint' Logitech mouse software, which was left over because I migrated my actual machine. I removed the software in 'Programs' and rebooted, then installed the guest additions. This worked.